# Why this strange Windows 7 backup failure?

Tags: windows-7, windows-7-backup

I don't understand why I'm getting this when trying to run the Windows backup tool.

```
An internal error has occured
The parameter is incorrect. (0x80070057)
```

[image]

Can you tell me what I should do about this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This knowledge base article (KB982736)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982736) suggests that the problem can be caused by having the decimal separator set to something other than `.`.  It suggests two solutions:

- Change the symbol back to `.` in **control panel** > **region and language** > **formats** > **additional settings**
- *or* set `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\System\CopyFileBufferedSynchronousIo` to `DWORD` value `1` using `regedit.exe`.

The KB article has more instructions on how to make the registry change.